# What is DataType in PostgreSql - Date format "YYYYMM"

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I am new to PostgreSql.

I want to store date as "YYYYMM" in my date column.

So, which data type should I use for my column? I tried finding it but didn't get. Any idea?

Comment: Vertica and Postgres are two **very** different database. Which one do you really use? But `DATE` columns do **not** have any format.

Comment: I want to know about postgreSql

Comment: Then why did you include Vertica?

Comment: Do not confuse data type used to store and data format used to display. For your "yyyymm" display format you can use date, integer or even varchar datatypes.

Comment: yyyymm is not a valid "date". Do you only want to store month/year (then you can't use a `date`) or do you just want to _display_ an existing date value as yyyymm?

Comment: Thanks all for you comments, I got it that date datatype can not be used in this case.